# I want to bind ViewModel to an HTML element dynamically increased with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

As an operation you want to do, copy an HTML element using jquery clone ()
I want to add the copied element and bind the ViewModel of knockout.js to the added element.
Is there a way to create and bind ViewModel newly for dynamically increased elements?

HTML

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.id_1_0">
  <div id="id_1_0" name="Table" data-bind="style: { top: Y() + 'px', height: Height() + 'px' }">
    <div data-bind="with: $root.id_2_0">
      <div id="id_7_1" name="Row1" data-bind="style: { top: Y() + 'px', height: Height() + 'px' }">
        <div data-bind="with: $root.id_8_1">
          <input data-bind="value: Value" name="TextField" type="text">
```

JavaScript

```
   let viewModels: any = {};
   for (Create ViewModel for the number of elements you want to bind) {
     let viewModel = new ViewModel();
     let key = "id_X_X";
     viewModels[key] = viewModel;
   }
   ko.applyBindings(viewModels);
```

Copy the element of Row 1 with JQuery.clone (true), add it as a sibling element, create a new ViewModel
I want to bind it, but I do not know how to do it.
If you bind it like the above script, the following error message will be output.

> You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

Comment: sound like you might be looking for a component http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html each component can have its own viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment you probably want a component or a template as opposed to jquery clone.  below is an example using a component.

```js
ko.components.register('form-input', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.inputValue = params.value;
        this.label = params.label
        this.id = params.id   
    },
    template:
        '<div data-bind="css: "form-group">\
             <label class="control-label col-sm-2" \
             data-bind ="attr: {for: id}"> \
             <span data-bind="text: label"></span>:</label>\
               <div class="col-sm-9">\
               <input type="text"\
                 class="form-control"\
                 data-bind="textInput: inputValue, attr: {id: id}"/> \
                 </div>\
            </div>'
});

function componentData(val){
var self = this;
this.val = ko.observable(val);
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.componentDataList = ko.observableArray('');
  this.numOfComponents = ko.observable('');
  this.generateComponents = function() {
    self.componentDataList.removeAll();
    for (i = 0; i < self.numOfComponents(); i++) {
      self.componentDataList.push(new componentData(i));
    }
  }
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <input class="form-control" 
  type="number" 
  data-bind="value: numOfComponents"
  placeholder="enter number of inputs you want"> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-bind = "click: generateComponents"> Go </button>
  </button>
  
  
  <div data-bind="foreach: componentDataList" >
    <form-input
     params="value: val,
             label: 'Input' + $index(), 
             id: 'datepicker' + $index() ">
   </form-input>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: I did not know about the template function so I learned a lot.
However, since the HTML described in the template is generated based on the external XML, it changes dynamically. I am wondering how to deal with it.

Comment: check out example two from the component loader documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html would that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that the template function can not be used in the application being created now.
I decided to bind it by specifying a stop HTML element to bind using with.

Ko.applyBindings (viewModel, HTMLElement);

Thank you for your cooperation.